# How to convert a dataframe to bytes without changing umlauts?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bytesio

I have a dataframe with umlauts in it. When I encode my dataframe to bytes, it changes all umlauts, regardles of setting the encoding to 'utf-8'.

Here is a small example:

```
data = {"Land" : ["Österreich", "Dänemark", "Detuschland"], "Column2" : ["äöü", "ÄÖÜ", "ß$'"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

```
byteData = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8').encode()
byteData

Output: b"Land,Column2\r\n\xc3\x96sterreich,\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc\r\nD\xc3\xa4nemark,\xc3\x84\xc3\x96\xc3\x9c\r\nDetuschland,\xc3\x9f$'\r\n"
```

Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Don’t encode to bytes .  You realize the display of byte strings never displays non-ASCII characters, and `C3 96`  are the two bytes `Ö` encodes to in UTF-8, right?

Comment: Yes I see now. I also see my problem. Österreich should be 
\xd6sterreich 
and not 
\xc3\x96sterreich.  
How do I encode it like that?

Comment: Ok I found it here: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). It was `cp1250`

Comment: Typically, you want UTF-8.  It can encode any Unicode character.  Single-byte code pages are limited to only 256 characters.

Answer (score 0):

try using `encoding='cp1252'` instead ;)